# jQuery Show TD one at a time on focus

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a registration form for my websites and I am trying to show different hidden td's as tips to my users when they focus on the inputs...

I've tried the closest(), next(), sibling(), hasClass() and cannot get this thing to work...any help is appreciated.  Here is the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/88JPU/1/

```
<style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
.focusField{  
    border:solid 2px #333;  
    background:lightyellow;   
}  
.idleField{  
     background:#fff;  
     border: solid 1px #DFDFDF;  
}  
input.text_field {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 200px;
}
input.text_field.with_box {
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 0;
}
.col-help {
    background:#f7f7f7;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    font-size:13px;
    font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif
}
</style>

<script>
$(function() {
    $('.col-help').hide();

    $('input[type="text"]').focus(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("idleField").addClass("focusField");
        $(this).closest('td').hasClass('col-help').show();
    });
});
</script>

<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>Full Name:</td>
  <td><input type="text" class="text_field name" id="name"/></td>
  <td class="col-help name" width="200 >what is your name</td>
<tr>
  <td>Password:</td><td><input type="text" class="text_field" id="password"/></td>
  <td class="col-help">Type a strong password...</td>
</tr>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: high could you post the formatted code please with the structure of your html

Comment: Those consecutive `</tr>` are incorrect. The first one must come before the second `<tr>`.

Comment: You also forgot to close a quote after `width="200`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/MLkDb/ (@Darin's answer doesn't hide the help when leaving the field).

However, you could make it even easier by using the `blur` event.. then you don't have to search for the previously selected element: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/MLkDb/1

Last but not least, you could also use pure CSS for the focus highlight and use JS only for showing the help box (with some changes it might be possible to do that via CSS, too): http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/MLkDb/2/

Some comments why your code didn't work:

- Unclosed quote -> breaking lots of your code since it's considered part of a tag argument
- `.hasClass()` returns a boolean - it doesn't filter the element list. In your case you need to use a selector.
- `.closest()` checks the element itself and its parents. Not the children/siblings of the element or its parents.
- You need to put the `. focusField` CSS rule after the `.text_field` rule or make its attributes `!important`. Otherwise they have lower priority than the later-defined attributes from `.text_field`.

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect...and thanks for the lesson on hasClass()

Answer (score 5):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/88JPU/10/):

```
$(this).parent().next('td.col-help').show();
```

Also you have wrongly nested `tr` tags.

And by the way if you are doing some form validation you might want to check the [jquery.validate plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/validation) instead of going through this manual work.

Comment: I think he also wants to hide the help and remove the focus style when leaving the field. But since he didn't mention that I've removed the downvote on your answer again.

Comment: @ThiefMaster, yes that's possible but as you say not part of the question. Anyway that's why I suggested the jquery validate plugin.